# Virtual Treeview How to only show children=isvisible and not mother (isinvisible=false)

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

If I make mother invisible. then child is also invisible..

I want to filter independant of the structure in the tree.. just show certain nodetypes?

So I want to show by filter children but not mother. It seems that if mother is invisible.. then children is by force invisible!

Any ideas to filter so?

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to present is not suitable for a Treeview in the first place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can do this using a recursive function that copies records from the source (unfiltered) dataset to the presentation (filtered) dataset based on any filter criteria you code for.

Comment: Thanks.. I asked for a  feature in Tree.. but as Uwe comment.. its against the nature of a tree. I was looking for a feature developed in Treeview/ thanks.